# Too many Windows 7 option on GRUB

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, grub, ubuntu-14.04

When I boot my Laptop, with a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 / Windows 7 PRO, I've noticed that I can select from 4 different Windows 7 options, instead the one and only I had some days ago.

Some of those aren't working at all: how can I "delete" the other 3 options on GRUB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries are in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Altough it is not recommended to edit the file. It ist generated by `update-grub`.

But I always made small edits in the file itself it never broke anything. Like renameing or deleting entries. Just saying be carefull and create a backup.

Comment: so I'll need to delete some records, after a backup, and then reboot? Just that?

Comment: Well, yes. If done right. Just make sure twice or more times, that you deleted the right ones. Use the displayed label in grub as reference for your search.

Comment: the fact is that 2 of them are working, and 2 aren't. the label is the same, i think they will only differ on the mounted device...